# Disable Location feature of the camera in Phonegap/Cordova app

Tags: cordova, geolocation, cordova-3

Is there an option to disable the geolocation of the camera in phonegap/cordova app. I am getting the following pop up when I capture an image:

> ... Would like to Use Your Current Location

I want that pop up to be disabled (not display to the end user). I disabled the geolocation plugin, but it didn't help.

Comment: I'm not sure when you say that you have disabled the geolocation plugin - does that mean that when you try "cordova plugin list" - does that plugin no longer show up? If so, did you do cordova build? After the build step - does you AndroidManifest.xml file have any more permissions-related tags? What other cordova plugins are you using?

Comment: See this answer to disable phonegap's location data embedding, which means it won't trigger the permission popup: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/18050379/5002032](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18050379/5002032)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove location services request from PhoneGap iOS 6 app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253139/how-to-remove-location-services-request-from-phonegap-ios-6-app)